# JWT Network Failure Issue

Tags: laravel, rest, jwt

I'm using Laravel 5.4 REST api with **JWT token**. I'm refreshing token for every request. What should I do in cause of any network failure before getting response from server.?

Comment: you can check the status code if you get 502 then it's a case of network failure by that you can handle network failures..

Comment: No I'm asking about network failure in mobile device.

Comment: Ok got it for that we can't handle it should be handled by client by managing status globally, may be using switch case if they got 502 then it is a case that server is unreachable and thus we won't get any request. Thus, from mobile side they will do a switch to handle this issue